# Convert data from JSON file to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON file like this:

```
[{
    "X_id": ["ID1"],
    "contents.value": ["Shanghai"],
    "contents.count": [23.7]
}, {
    "X_id": ["ID2"],
    "contents.value": ["Lagos"],
    "contents.count": [16.1]
}, {
    "X_id": ["ID3"],
    "contents.value": ["Instanbul"],
    "contents.count": [14.2]
}, {
    "X_id": ["ID4"],
    "contents.value": ["Karachi"],
    "contents.count": [14.0]
}, {
    "X_id": ["ID5"],
    "contents.value": ["Mumbai"],
    "contents.count": [12.5]
}]
```

I want to convert the data in this file to an array to look like this:

```
var series = [
    ['Shanghai', 23.7],
    ['Lagos', 16.1],
    ['Instanbul', 14.2],
    ['Karachi', 14.0],
    ['Mumbai', 12.5]
];
```

So this is the code I tried for that:

```
var series = [];
$.getJSON("example.json", function(data) {})
.done(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        series.push([item['contents.value'][0], item['contents.count'][0]])
    });
})
.fail(function() {})
.always(function(data) {});
```

I use this array as a source of data for a function, and the first `series` variable is working for me, but I want to get the data from that JSON file who looks like that, but the second `series` variable didn't work for me.

I tried to `console.log()` the both vars and this is how the result looks:

[image]

You can see that for the first variable the content of the array is displayed on the console, but for the second variable it is not it's displayed like this: `[]` and to see it's content I have to click on it and then the console shows this:

[image]

So how can I make the second array looks like the first one?

Comment: You are getting valid response. go ahead and let us know whether its working as expected or not!

Comment: @RayonDabre no it's not working as I expect actually I use that array as a source for a chart when I hard code the array as in the first series variable the chart shows stats, but when I use the array which I created using the json file the chart shows nothing if you want me to upload the example I will

Comment: But both the arrays are identical, You must be missing something in initialization of `chart`

Comment: @RayonDabre I'm not missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'use strict'

let data = [{
    "X_id": ["ID1"],
    "contents.value": ["Shanghai"],
    "contents.count": [23.7]
}, {
    "X_id": ["ID2"],
    "contents.value": ["Lagos"],
    "contents.count": [16.1]
}, {
    "X_id": ["ID3"],
    "contents.value": ["Instanbul"],
    "contents.count": [14.2]
}, {
    "X_id": ["ID4"],
    "contents.value": ["Karachi"],
    "contents.count": [14.0]
}, {
    "X_id": ["ID5"],
    "contents.value": ["Mumbai"],
    "contents.count": [12.5]
}]

let result = data.map((item) => {
    return [
        item['contents.value'][0],
        item['contents.count'][0],
    ]
})

console.log(result)
```

output

```
[ [ 'Shanghai', 23.7 ],
  [ 'Lagos', 16.1 ],
  [ 'Instanbul', 14.2 ],
  [ 'Karachi', 14 ],
  [ 'Mumbai', 12.5 ] ]
```

Comment: this worked when I used the content of the json file inside my script code as you showed in your example but when I tried to use the json file it didnt work

Comment: @LamyaLam did you parse json data?